# instantiate the implementation class of Depenency injection using unity framework in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I have a login controller which accept the instance of user and in login method it call the 
Validate user correctly but the problem arises in UserManager if i include a constructor in a similar manner

```
    public LoginController(IUser user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }
    [httpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(UserLogin model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           // var userMgr = new UserManager();

            if (user.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {

                  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is        incorrect.");
            }
            // return View("UserLogin");
        }
```

following is where the problem arises

```
 public class UserManager : IUser 
 {

     IUser _user;

    public UserManager(IUser user)
   {
      _user=user;
   }

   public void displayUser()
   {
      //.......
     //.....    

   }

  public void somefunction()
 {
    _user.displayUser();
 }
```

}

The reason i am using the UserManager() constructor is because because i want to use _user.displayUser()

I have made the configuration in global.aspx like the following

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        var container = Container.InitContainer();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
     }
```

and Container.InitContainer() call the following class

```
       public static class Container
       {
         public static IUnityContainer InitContainer()
         {

            var container = new UnityContainer();
          // Register the relevant types for the         

          // container here through classes or configuration    

          //container.RegisterType<IUser, UserManager>(new                         ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        container.RegisterType<IUser, UserManager>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());



        return container;

    }
```

and I have UnityDepdendency resolver class as follows

```
   public class UnityDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
   {
        private IUnityContainer _container;

      #region Ctor

      public UnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
      {

          _container = container;

      }



    #endregion

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {

            return _container.Resolve(serviceType);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return null;

        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {

            return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return new List<object>();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have an `UserManager` class that must be injected into itself? And how on earth do you think this is possible, even without a DI container?

Comment: Hi i am new to DI & Unity framework and was wondering if i could configure in such a way that I could use constructor to set the instance in UserManager is it possible to do that ?cus i dont want to user UserManager userobj=new UserManager() in UserManager Class

Comment: But why? What is the use of creating a new `UserManager` inside the `UserManager` class. Take a step back and look at the design. Why not simply do: `public void somefunction() { this.displayUser(); }`???

Answer (score 1):

We can use `this.displayUser();`

`UserManager userobj=new UserManager()`  is not required